# Cannot read property 'forExport' of undefined when leaving the page with Highcharts chart

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I can reproduce the problem in a very simple Angular-Highcharts application. When I retrieve the data from the server, and then leave the page with Highcharts chart, I am getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'forExport' of undefined
> at a.destroy (highcharts.js:394)
> at HighchartsChartComponent.ngOnDestroy (highcharts-angular.js:44)

Not surprisingly, `HighchartsChartComponent.ngOnDestroy` is

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.chart) { // #56
        this.chart.destroy();
        this.chart = null;
    }
}
```

Here is the minimal example:

```
export class WeatherForecastComponent implements OnInit {
  highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = { ... };

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<any[]>(`http://localhost:57432/WeatherForecast`, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
    })})
    .subscribe(result => {
        let categories: string[] = [];
        let dataSeries: number[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            categories.push(result[i]['location']);
            dataSeries.push(result[i]['temperatureC']);
        }
        this.chartOptions.xAxis = {
            categories: categories
        };
        this.chartOptions.series = [{
          type: "column",
          name: "Cities",
          data: dataSeries
        }];
     this.highcharts.chart('container', this.chartOptions);
     }, error => {
         console.log(error);
     });
  }
}
```

I saw a number of similar issues both on Stack Overflow and on Github. I *understand* that the root cause is that it's trying delete the chart that is already deleted. But all of them are deleting (or attempting to delete) the charts in application code.

I tried to delete the chart in `ngOnDestroy()`, or to unsubscribe - but no difference.

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/virshu/HichartsException), including Server-side code.

Note, that the problem *doesn't* happen when it is a "hardcoded" chart.

Angular: 12.2; Highchars 9.2.2; Highcharts-Angular: 2.10.0

Comment: Could you please create an online demo with your example that I could debug it properly? Or please explain how to run the server locally. (preferably the first one) ;)

Comment: A little strange - it's one of the easiest problems to reproduce. But sure - you can access the site at https://aws.digitalelasticity.xyz/ . Click on Weather, and then back on Home - and you will see the problem in F12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main things that don't work.
But before I could explain let's look at the code responsible for creating the chart in the wrapper.

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
        const update = changes.update && changes.update.currentValue;
        if (changes.options || update) {
            this.wrappedUpdateOrCreateChart();
            if (update) {
                this.updateChange.emit(false); // clear the flag after update
            }
        }
    }
    wrappedUpdateOrCreateChart() {
        if (this.runOutsideAngular) {
            this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
                this.updateOrCreateChart();
            });
        }
        else {
            this.updateOrCreateChart();
        }
    }
    updateOrCreateChart() {
        if (this.chart && this.chart.update) {
            this.chart.update(this.options, true, this.oneToOne || false);
        }
        else {
            this.chart = this.Highcharts[this.constructorType || 'chart'](this.el.nativeElement, this.options, this.callbackFunction || null);
            // emit chart instance on init
            this.chartInstance.emit(this.chart);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, everything is happening in the `ngOnChanges` hook. If the change is detected the series of methods are fired to finally update the chart.

And now the things which don't work:

1. In the case when there is any asynchronous code happening in the `subscribe` (like for example HTTP request - on my example mocked by `setTimeout`) you have to manually set to wrapper that is should be updated by setting the `updateFlag`. Because Angular doesn't detect changes in some properties in the `chartOptions`.
2. If you split assigning properties to the `chartOptions` like in the code snippet below set the `oneToOne` flag to `true`

```
     this.chartOptions.xAxis = {
            categories: categories
          };
          this.chartOptions.series = [{
            type: "column",
            name: "Cities",
            data: dataSeries
          }];
```

**Docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#options-details

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-vwrrmx**

Comment: Thank you. `updateFlag` **and** `oneToOne` flag together make it work

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing that isn't necessary inside your code that causes that issue.
You don't have to destroy the chart reference here. When you remove that everything works as expected.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.chartRef.destroy()
}
```

Please also note that creating a second chart inside the `subscribe` isn't ideal. Insted use `updateFlag`.

```
this.highcharts.chart('container', this.chartOptions);
```

**Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-nxzqvy**

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in my question, I used `onDestroy` and `chartRef` and callback function for test purposes only. I update github for the reference and the problem still exists. Can you elaborate on the `updateFlag`? I don't see it assigned anywhere in your code. It seems that if you change your code to retrieve data through HTTP, rather than locally, - you will get a problem as well

Comment: I see that with hardcoded `of()` the chart shows up even without what you call *second chart*; but with `http` call it doesn't. And also with hardcoded option it doesn't crash, whereas with `http` it does.

Comment: Also, I tried to find any documentation on updateFlag, without success; and since you didn't put any code in stackblitz - I am left guessing. All examples that I found relate to situation when the code changes the chart *in response* to user actions. For me it is not really updating anything - unless the chart gets generated *before* `subscribe()` is invoked (looks like it). If your recommendation is to use `updateFlag` in this context as well - please provide some guidance! Thank you

Comment: Indeed your `getData` method works well and the chart is created and destroyed properly. I'll try to debug the other one.